# Admob RewardedAd how to know if the user closed the video before receiving the award?

Tags: java, android, admob

I'm migrating the app to new version of **'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:21.1.0'**

Before, I used the "`onRewardedVideoAdClosed`" method to find out if the user had finished displaying the video.

Now I check if the user received the award in the listener:

```
if (mRewardedAd != null) {
                Activity activityContext = MainActivity.this;
                mRewardedAd.show(activityContext, new OnUserEarnedRewardListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onUserEarnedReward(@NonNull RewardItem rewardItem) {
                        // Handle the reward.
                        Log.d("TAG", "The user earned the reward.");
                        int rewardAmount = rewardItem.getAmount();
                        String rewardType = rewardItem.getType();
        
                        Toast.makeText(activityContext, "Amount: "+rewardAmount+"\nType: "+rewardType, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
    } else {
           Log.d("TAG", "The rewarded ad wasn't ready yet.");
    }
```

My question is how can I know if the user watched the video until the end to receive the award?
In fact, my prize is a media file download, so if the user clicked on the X in the ad, I need to send a message to watch the video until the end!

Answer (score 0):

You will be fully clear if u look into this web page : https://developer.android.com/codelabs/admob-rewarded-video-android

Comment: If you took the trouble to understand that the library has changed and you can no longer verify that the video has been closed, you would not post this year 2020 google link

Comment: sorry for that, I would look into this link now then.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).